# makefile: performing include to a .mak file after certain action on it

Tags: makefile

I have a large project I'm working on, in which I want to perform `include` to some .mak file, but only after I make change to this file content via a command inside the original makefile. Since it's a large project it will be hard to write code, so I will give this ridiculous example instead:

I have some small C project that all it's C and header files are in the same directory, and I need to write a makefile. I'm not allowed to use `clean` rule in the makefile I write, but I have a file named `file.mak` that I can include in my makefile. Content of `file.mak`:

```
.PHONY: clean

cleam:
    $(RM) $(objs) test
```

The problem here is that the rule is `cleam` and not `clean`. I'm also not allowed to change manually `file.mak` , but I'm allowed to do this with a command inside the original makefile. This can be done easily by:

```
sed -i 's/cleam/clean/g' file.mak
```

So I thought of writing the makefile like this:

```
CC = gcc
srcs = $(wildcard ./*.c)
objs = $(srcs:.c=.o)


test: $(objs) change_file include_file
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

change_file:
    $(shell sed -i 's/cleam/clean/g' file.mak)

include_file: change_file
    include file.mak
```

But I get the following error:

```
include: Command not found
```

So I understand that there is a problem of using include inside a rule, so is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

(GNU) `make` has a feature [Remaking Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html) that can be used for scenarios like this, but your approach is wrong. `include` is a directive and can't be used in a recipe.

Instead, when you `include` a file, `make` first checks for rules creating *this exact file* and executes them. As in your case, the file you want to include already exists, you have to make this rule `.PHONY` to force its execution. It would look like this:

```
.PHONY: file.mak

file.mak:
    sed -i 's/cleam/clean/g' file.mak

include file.mak
```

As a more robust alternative (without the need for a *phony* rule), consider creating a fixed version (copy) and include this:

```
file_fixed.mak: file.mak
    sed -e 's/cleam/clean/g' <file.mak >file_fixed.mak

include file_fixed.mak
```

Comment: May I add as good and well documented as make is, eventually, it is too low level a tool, and I would suggest generation of makefiles by tools like CMake. They have been in use long enough to be reliable and predictable. IMHO.

Comment: Using my own build-system based **only** on GNU make, I don't agree with this :) But I have to admit the amount of learning is a lot for using GNU make correctly and flexibly and many might find it easier to use additional tools ... just IMHO stay away from GNU autotools, or else you might loose your hair :)

Comment: The problem with autotools is once you go autotools hard, it eats so much of your time, you absolutely have to justify it by using autotools of everything.

For me it cuts to simple: how many lines of code I have to maintain?

"my own build-system" is exactly against that approach.

if you're doing it, and you have convinced your customer/employer to let you do it....good for you. Just let's be clear: it's not in their best interest.

(unless you're the author of open project like scons, cmake, or all those newer thingies I never keep up with remembering the names of)